# jquery slick slider is undefined using wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to implement a slick slider in a wordpress website. the jquery isnt working. Am i doing something wrong because im not seeing a error.

```
 ;(function($){
class SlickCarousel {
    constructor() {
        this.initiateCarousel();
    }

    initiateCarousel() {
        console.log('works');
        $('.post-carousel').slick();
    }
}
new SlickCarousel(); })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Do you get the 'works' message in the console? does the element `.post-carousel` exist? try adding `;` before and after your snippet.

Comment: change `(jQuery)` to `(jQuery || $)`, if that does not work then check you are even loading the lib, why do you need make it a class?

Answer (score 0):

replace `$` with `jQuery` in all instances - the `$` conflicts with WP code.